# He's on the floor

Tags: phrases

He's on the floor.

Does it mean "He has fell on the floor"?

Could you please translate "He's on the floor" into simple english?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: 'He is on the floor' _is_ simple English! On its own, it just means that he is lying (or sitting) on the floor. The man in the picture _has fallen_ out of bed and that is why he is lying on the floor.

Comment: Thank you, Kate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In isolation, "he's on the floor" does not necessarily mean that somebody fell.

"On" is a preposition "*used to show that something is in a position above something else and touching it, or that something is moving into such a position*" (Cambridge dictionary). "He is on the floor" seems like the most basic of all English grammar examples, just like "the pen is on the table". It literally means that 'he' (which must refer to someone you have already mentioned or who is observable so as to be obvious who you are referring to) is currently in contact with the floor.

The statement might well *imply* that the person has fallen, depending on the context or circumstances. For example, the image you included in your question shows a man who has fallen out of bed. If you thought someone was safely sleeping in their bed and were then told that they were on the floor, you would assume that they had fallen out of bed. However, if someone said "the *rug* is on the floor", that is the place you would expect a rug to be so there would be no implication of an accident.

If you want to explicitly state that he has fallen, you could say either:

- he has fallen on the floor.
- he fell on the floor.

Comment: Thank you, Astralbee